Camera quality on S21 worse than on A51
I switched from iOS to Android 2.5 years ago. I bought a Samsung Galaxy S21 which I have been happy with, the camera was perfect and colorful. Now 2.5 years later, the camera quality is much worse, the colors are not so bright and it's all like greyed out. My girlfriend has just bought a new Samsung Galaxy A51 which is supposed to have a worse camera - it's also a "lower series" phone. Her photos are much brighter and more colorful than mine, they can not be even compared.
I have heard Samsung (Android) is doing this to make people buy new phones often. Is that true? Is there something I can do about it if I don't want to buy a new phone yet? Maybe it's just some wrong setting...

To make an equal comparison, did both of you use the same Camera app? The stock Samsung Camera? Did you accidentally turn on Filter (a magic wand icon on the top right)?

And in addition also compare the photos on the same device in their original format to not compare the displays but the camera..

Yes we use the same camera app. And there are no filters as we compared settings, also we shared photos with each other and the difference is visible.

To my knowledge, Samsung is not doing any such thing.  The obvious (to me) conclusion is that

Either the camera on your phone is damaged
Or you have changed some setting
Or you have installed an app that has reconfigured the camera.


Not aware of anything like that. I guess I will have to ask in a samsung shop, thanks.
